# remove last value if a number otherwise do nothing

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula for Microsoft Excel:

> If the last value from a cell is a number then delete the value from the cell otherwise do leave the same content

```
=IF(OR((LEN(B2)>1),(LEN(B2)<7)),LEFT(B2, LEN(B2)-1),B2)
```

this is what I have tried but I am sure this is not the right way to do it, I have values where is 20152 and _thisform1 and _thisotherform so the length it is not the same for cells.

I would want to from from `20152` to `2015` and from `_thisform1` to `_thisform` and leaving `_thisotherform` as is.

Comment: You cannot "Delete" a value from the cell using a worksheet function. You can use a formula to return a different value, however. Is this what you are actually wanting?

Comment: Yes that can work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(B2)),LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1),B2)
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, it really helped me. I have a follow up questions if I need to create another post I can do that too, but I was wondering if the cell start with a letter but end with a number then to skip that line too.
Test_2232